# Best way to recieve props from child to parent react component

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have an array which I want to save in my database. I have a page (parent component) and a form (child component) where my birthday input is (the one I'm saving in database). The select html elements are in the child component, and I take their values after every change. Now I need to pass recieved values from select elements back to my parent component and update the array with the recieved props. I will try to recreate my code as best as I can:

**AuthenticationPage.js (Parent):**

```
import React from 'react';

class AuthenticationPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state({
            setMonth:null
            setDay:null
            setYear:null
        })
    }
    render() {
        return(
           <div>
           <SignupForm // This is where I call my child component
            onChange={(monthValue) => this.setState({ setMonth: monthValue })}
            initialValues={{ 
              dateofbirth: [
                {
                  month: this.state.setMonth, // This one is okey but I can use onChange just to change one state
                  day: this.state.setDay,
                  year: this.state.setYear
                }
              ]
            }}
            />
           </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AuthenticationPage;
```

**SignupForm.js (Child):**

```
import React from "react";
import SelectSearch from "react-select-search";

const SignupForm = (props) => (
  <FinalForm
    {...props}
    render={(fieldRenderProps) => {
      const { 
      // Here I render props from parent component
      } = fieldRenderProps;

      function monthPicker(monthValue) {
        props.onChange(monthValue);
        // How can I update the state of setDay and setYear states in parent component
      }

      return (
        <Form className={classes} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <SelectSearch
            options={month}
            onChange={(monthValue) => monthPicker(monthValue)} // This is ok, I change setMonth state in parent with this function
          />
          <SelectSearch
            options={day}
            // How to work with this, this is day input
          />
          <SelectSearch
            options={year}
            // How to work with this, this is year input
          />
        </Form>
      );
    }}
  />
);

export default SignupForm;
```

So basically I want to update states in parent component after onChange happens on select elements in my child component. I'm new to React and I can't figure this out whole day, so any help will mean a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Child should receive a 'onChange' function prop. That will be called inside the child component, every time the values on the form are changed (`this.props.onChange(newValue)`).

The parent should hold a state of the values that will be updated accordingly (`<SignupForm ... onChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ value: newValue })} />`)

Comment: This works good but how can I work with it with the three select items? I need to get the values from each and I can only use one onChange on SignupForm

Comment: child component: `this.props.onChange({ [itemType]: itemValue })`

Comment: parent component: `onChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ value: ...this.state.value, ...newValue })}`

Comment: Please see my answer and if you can recreate it in code, I have updated it with the latest try, I included your code, would much appriciate it. How can I then refer it to the right state in parent?

Comment: What should be the itemtype?

Answer (score 0):

From parent to child you can pass data through props, but from child to parent best way is by function , i ll try to write an example below, i always code with functional component so my syntax won't be right below, but i hope you ll get the idea ...

> Parent Component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state({
            monthValue:null
        })
    }

// this function send as a prop
const updateMonthValue =(value)=>{
  this.state.monthValue=value
}
  render() {
    return <Child updateMonthValue={updateMonthValue} />;
  }
}
```

> Child Component

```
const Child =(props) => {
  const submitHandler =(value) =>{
    //here you can call the function of parent and the function in the parent will update state of parent
    props.updateMonthValue(value)
  }
  render() {
    return <h1><button onClick={()=>submitHandler("june")} /></h1>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend! I tried your code but I recieved this error: TypeError: props.updateMonthValue is not a function, the error is called in child component

Comment: I was able to modify your code to fit my needs, its perfect! Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Vuk i am glad to hear that !

Comment: "this.state.monthValue=value" ----> do not do this in react, you need to use setstate for this, if you do this that way your render function wont run and you wont see the changes.